# How to view help instructions in Oracle Weblogic 11g console

Tags: oracle, console, oracle11g, weblogic11g

I just installed Oracle Weblogic 11g with the zip developper package on Linux.
I managed to create a domain, servers declare a machine, start the nodemanager however, I cannot access the help links inside it : when I click on a link, an xml file which starts with

```
<portal:root xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/servers/netuix/xsd/portal/support/1.0.0 portal-support-1_0_0.xsd">
−
<!--

    Overall portal definition file for BEA Help Viewer.
    Copyright (c) 2008,2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
-->
−
<netuix:desktop encoding="UTF-8" definitionLabel="helpDesktopLabel" markupName="desktop" markupType="Desktop" title="home.page.title" backingFile="com.bea.help.utils.GeneralBackingFile" treeOptimizationEnabled="true">
```

is downloaded.

Can you tell me how to configure the console to display the help ? or to install the help ?

Note : I also install the supplemental dev zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the help is only deployed in production mode, not when unzipping the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing with WebLogic 12.c.

You might want to check this link however, it seems to have steps on how to configure the Help facility, which is build on the Open Source JavaHelp 2.0:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24966/addcustomhelp.htm

So far, I found a bug in the link to the JavaHelp project which is referenced on the above link, but this link works instead: http://java.net/projects/javahelp

Answer (score 1):

Also, here is a current link to the JavaHelp reference manual: 
http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/jhug.pdf

p.s.  I tried to add this link to my previous post, but more than two links are considered spam, so was unable to do so.